# Kentico transformation on a repeater with a custom query

Tags: sql, transformation, kentico

I have a MS SQL database table that contains information on courses for a college. This is the custom query inside of the repeater with custom query that is currently being used in Kentico (I didn't write this).

```
SELECT 'ALL' AS Course,
'All' AS CourseProgram,
'1' as ID

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT SUBJ_CODE AS COURSE
SUBJ_DESC AS CourseProgram,
NULL AS ID
ORDER BY ID DESC, Course
```

As of right now, the classes are ordered by Course Title and each section is listed seperately...

```
courseName1 - courseCode1 - courseNum1 - courseSection1
Course Information

courseName1 - courseCode1 - courseNum1 - courseSection2
Course Information
```

If the Course Name, Course Code, and Course Number are the same... I would like the course sections to be listed underneath. Similar to this...

```
courseName1 - courseCode1 - courseNum1
--- courseSection1 - Course Information
--- courseSection2 - Course Information
```

I was told the best way to do this would be to use a transformation inside of the Repeater with custom query, rather than putting a repeater inside of a repeater.

I thought the easiest way to do this would be to make the courseName, courseCode, or courseNum as heading. Then have a loop that checks if the heading has changed. Someone wrote up some pseudo code, but I'm new to Kentico and not sure this will work / what it means.

```
{%
heading = courseNum
isNewHeading = true;
If(isNewHeading) {
text = "<option value=\""+Course+"\">"+courseProgram+"</option>";
courseNum
}
return text;
#%}
```

Any help would be appreciated. I'm not sure where to go from here being new to Kentico and not writing the original code. Thanks!

Comment: FYI that's no pseudo code, it's K# a Kentico specific macro language. You can find more information on the syntax here: https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Macro+syntax There is also an video available, which can be found here (please note some macros aren't available since then and more were added): https://vimeo.com/8197623

Answer (score 0):

In the repeater you need to select your classes. In the transformation you can use K# syntax to retrive all courses matching the class.

You didn't wrote what is the course, is it page type?
If the courses and classes are page types and the courses are childs of classes you can setup similar repeater:

Repeater - make sure that in columns you have NodeAliasPath

In the transformation

```
{%CourseName%} {%CourseSection%} {%CourseNum%}
{% Documents[NodeAliasPath].Children.WithAllData.ApplyTransformation("namespace.class.transformationcodename") %}
```

It will select all documents under classes. You should optimize this transformation to better performance.

Answer (score 0):

Having a nested repeater vs. a nested query is really no different aside from you can set caching on the repeater whereas with a query its quite a bit harder to.  In my opinion, your best bet is to write a [custom transformation method](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K8/Adding+custom+methods+to+transformations) for this.  This way you can set caching and optimize your query so it's not taxing on your system.

Another option is to make the data setup in a hierarchical format.  Then you can use the hierarchical viewer to display your data which, in my opinion, is optimized for things like this.  [Here is a good article](http://devnet.kentico.com/articles/displaying-data-hierarchically) on loading hierarchical data within Kentico.